# Sort a list containing objects that have datetime attributes

Tags: python, python-datetime

I have excel files with data about student test scores, they can take a test up to three times but I need my program to recognize the order in which they took them and the excel file is not in order. I have a `Student` class that holds a list of  objects representing all of the student's attempts and an `Attempt` class, that includes the score and date/time the test was taken.

```
import datetime as dt

class Student:
    def __init__(self, last_name, first_name ):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

        # will hold Attempt objects that consist of score and date/time test taken
        self.attempts = []

    # I imagine I need something like this
    def order_attempts(self):
        for attempt in self.attempts:
            # compare attempt.date_and_time_of_attempt to next attempt and switch if needed/create a new Student.ordered_attempts attribute?

class Attempt:
    def __init__(self, score_as_fraction, datetime_obj):
        self.score_as_fraction = score_as_fraction
        self.date_and_time_of_attempt = datetime_obj
```

In my main.py, skipping all the data scraping and splitting from excel, I am looping through each row and building these objects as such:

```
import datetime as dt
datetime_obj = dt.datetime(int(year), int(month), int(day), int(hour), int(minute))
attempt_obj = Attempt(score_as_fraction, datetime_obj)
student_obj.attempts.append(attempt_obj)
```

So say after reading one excel file one student took the test 3 times so an imaginary `student_obj.attempts = [<attempt.Attempt object at 0x105294da0>, <attempt.Attempt object at 0x102431c50>,<attempt.Attempt object at 0x105294f28>]` exists but that list is in the order of the excel file, not by time of attempt. Is there any way to reorder this `attempts` list from first attempt to last attempt? I would show what I have tried but I am honestly not sure what to attempt. I think I included all the info necessary but if you need more please let me know. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Excel date/times can be ordered by the date number, it's not even necessary to convert them to datetime first.

Comment: I built this entire thing how I needed it, realized the attempts were out of order and rebuilt with this datetime idea. Wish I had tried that first lol. Thanks, will go try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest giving a representation for an Attempt like what I have added.
You can sort any type of list using a key. To get the "key" to sort an attempt, I want to tell that the `sorted` method that an attempt is represented by its datetime. Therefore, using `lambda`, we can achieve that. Googling these terms will get you what you want. Here's a sample code:

```
from datetime import date,datetime,timedelta

class Student:
    def __init__(self, last_name, first_name ):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name

        # will hold Attempt objects that consist of score and date/time test taken
        self.attempts = []

    # I imagine I need something like this
    def order_attempts(self):
        self.attempts = sorted(self.attempts,key= lambda attempt:attempt.date_and_time_of_attempt)

class Attempt:
    def __init__(self, score_as_fraction, datetime_obj):
        self.score_as_fraction = score_as_fraction
        self.date_and_time_of_attempt = datetime_obj
    def __repr__(self):
        return str(self.date_and_time_of_attempt)+': '+str(self.score_as_fraction)

student = Student('Doe','John')
student.attempts=[Attempt(0.8,date.today()), Attempt(0.7,date.today() + timedelta(days=1)), Attempt(0.6,date.today() - timedelta(days=1))]
print(student.attempts)
student.order_attempts()
print(student.attempts)
```

giving:

```
[2021-03-05: 0.8, 2021-03-06: 0.7, 2021-03-04: 0.6]
[2021-03-04: 0.6, 2021-03-05: 0.8, 2021-03-06: 0.7]
```

Comment: Thank you! I am doing this work for a college and everything I am doing manually, a computer should be handling. Once this is done I will be saving countless hours. Almost done. Also learned something  new and that is always great. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use use the `date_and_time_of_attempt` attribute of the attempt object as a sorting key

```py
self.attempts.sort(key = lambda attempt: attempt.date_and_time_of_attempt)
```

Comment: Super elegant. Just learned something. Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 1):

With the code you have posted, and also mentioning that you would be passing an excel file, you couldn't do it by just the code you posted. You would have to actually read the excel file and capture those datetime obj values. But, if you are getting actual datetime objects from what you posted, you could simply use `list.sort()` to sort a list of objects in place

```
import datetime

yesterday = datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
today = datetime.date.today()
tomorrow = datetime.date.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

date_list =[today, tomorrow, yesterday]
print(date_list)
```

[image]

```
date_list.sort()
print(date_list)
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for not making that more clear, I didn't want to include all of the scrapping code but I grab a date from excel in the format '02/26/2021 06:27 PM', split that into `year`, `month`, `day`, `hour` and `minute` objects and create datetime objects from it. But I am unsure how I would apply this as I can't say `Student.attempts.sort()` since that is a list of `Attempt` objects, and they each have an `Attempt.date_and_time_of_attempt` attribute storing a `datetime` object. I think I might have approached this in the wrong way.

Comment: Does my post answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

I think the question is really how to sort instances of Attempt. You can do this by making the Class Attempt sortable by adding a method `__lt__`, see the example below.

```
from datetime import datetime

class Student:

    def __init__(self, name, attempts):
        self.name = name
        self.attempts = attempts

    def order_attempts(self, reverse=False):
        self.attemtps = attempts.sort(reverse=reverse)

class Attempt:

    def __init__(self, topic, attempt_date, score):
        self.score = score
        self.attempt_date = attempt_date
        self.topic = topic

    def __lt__(self, other):
        return self.attempt_date < other.attempt_date

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.attempt_date.date()}: {self.score}'

attempts = []
attempts.append(Attempt('Math', datetime(2021, 2, 3), 4))
attempts.append(Attempt('Math', datetime(2021, 2, 5), 5))
attempts.append(Attempt('Math', datetime(2021, 2, 7), 8))
stud2 = Student('Mike Owen', attempts)

stud2.order_attempts()
print(stud2.attempts)
stud2.order_attempts(reverse=True)
print(stud2.attempts)
```

```
[2021-02-03: 4, 2021-02-05: 5, 2021-02-07: 8]
[2021-02-07: 8, 2021-02-05: 5, 2021-02-03: 4]
```